# Difficulties deleting memory

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm having some trouble working with memory: I have to keep a copy of some data in a new class. The main problem is that the first 9 bytes of this data should be thrown away. Whenever the object gets deleted though, I either get a segmentation fault or SIGABRT (it's not even consistent)

```
class Frame
{
public:
    Frame();
    ~Frame();

    void setFirstData(uint8_t *data, size_t dataLength);
    void setSecondData(uint8_t *data, size_t dataLength);
    void setThirdData(uint8_t *data, size_t dataLength);
    void setFourthData(uint8_t *data, size_t dataLength);

    ...

private:
    unsigned char *_firstData;
    bool _firstDataSet;
    size_t _firstDataLength;
    unsigned char *_secondData;
    bool _secondDataSet;
    size_t _secondDataLength;
    unsigned char *_thirdData;
    bool _thirdDataSet;
    size_t _thirdDataLength;
    unsigned char *_fourthData;
    bool _fourthDataSet;
    size_t _fourthDataLength;
};

Frame::Frame()
{
    _firstDataSet = false;
    _secondDataSet = false;
    _thirdDataSet = false;
    _fourthDataSet = false;
}

Frame::~Frame()
{
    if (_firstDataSet)
        delete [] _firstData;
    if (_secondDataSet)
        delete[] _secondData;
    if (_thirdDataSet)
        delete[] _thirdData;
    if (_fourthDataSet)
        delete[] _fourthData;
}

void Frame::setFirstData(uint8_t *data, size_t dataLength)
{
    //copy all the data in a unsigned char*, except for the first 9 bytes
    _firstDataLength = dataLength - 9;
    _firstData = new unsigned char[_firstDataLength];
    memcpy(_firstData, data + 9, _firstDataLength*sizeof(*_firstData));
    /*for (int i = 0; i < dataLength - 9; i++)
    {
        _firstData[i] = (unsigned char) data[i + 9];
    }*/
    _firstDataSet = true;
}
```

The other setData functions are identical to setFirstData, but with the correct arrays.

Am I supposed to use something else than memcpy? Or is the usage wrong? The commented for loop was my original method of 'copying' the data but I dont think it actually copies the data (original array will be deleted when the copied data still has to be available).

EDIT: I added the qt tag because i'm working in a Qt environment and using some Qt classes for GUI. I don't think qt has anything to do with these basic C++ functions.

Comment: Where do you set _firstData ?

Comment: You allocate and assign to _data yet you are doing the delete on _firstData. Where do you clean up `_data`?

Comment: Where does _firstData come from?  If you dereference it without setting it, then behavior is of course undefined.

Comment: prefix underscore is not a very good convention, because a lot of implementation identifiers use that convention (and it's therefore reserved in the global namespace). suffix underscore is OK, e.g. used in Boost. prefix "my" or "m" is also OK.

Comment: it's a good idea to add an `assert( dataLength >= 9 )`.

Comment: `memcpy` is technically OK, but it's generally (not in this particular case) more safe to use `std::copy`. this `std::copy` is preferable as a convention or default choice of copying function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually receiving 4 packets of data but for simplifying I thought I'd remove the 'first'everywhere. I forgot it there...

Comment: @JelcoAdamczyk: after that edit the code is still wrong due to incomplete name fixups. better post the **real code**. and do post the complete class definition.

Comment: instead of using raw pointers and `new`, use `std::vector`: it's what it's there *for*.

Comment: Can you please remove the qt tag? Thanks.

Comment: updated the code to what i actually have

Comment: Also I get the uint8_t *data externally, so I can't use std::vector sadly enough

Answer (score 0):

What with setting `firstData`:

```
   _firstData = new unsigned char[_dataLength];
    memcpy(_firstData, data + 9, _dataLength*sizeof(*_firstData));
```